# There was a path error when Ubuntu created AVD via avdmanager

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I used the command line tools provided by Android to download the SDK tools.Use the command `avdmanager create avd -n nexus5_23 -k "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86_64" --device "Nexus 5"` to create the emulator, I found that the mirror path in the file `config.ini` was `image.sysdir.1=sdk/system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86_64/`.

Compared with the emulator path created by Win10, the emulator can be started normally after changing it to `image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86_64/`.

I can't find a solution to this problem in Google.Can you give me some Suggestions? thank you.

The environment:

- Ubuntu 16.04 Server
- bash.rc

```
...

export REPO_OS_OVERRIDE=linux

# ANDROID SDK
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/yaorc/android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/yaorc/android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:${ANDROID_HOME}/build-tools/29.0.3
export PATH=$PATH:${ANDROID_HOME}/platforms/android-29
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after several attempts.

Because my `command-line tools` are in the SDK root,This causes the system image path to be confused when the `avdmanager` creates the AVD.

Solution:

I created the `cmdline` directory in the SDK root, cut the `tools` folder into the `cmdline`, and modified the environment variable file to properly create and start avd.